# Fastest way of creating XML from parent-child table in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, parent-child

Assume we have some DataTable or IEnumerable with ChildID, ParentID and Title. 
We need to serialize it to XML like

```
<Entity title="">
   <Entity title=""></Entity>
   <Entity title=""></Entity>
</Entity>
```

As i found out, standard DataTable.GetXML() returns something different. I thought about initializing class tree like Entity e = new Entity(ID, Title, ParentEntityID) and then serializing it. Table is about > 3000 elems. Is there faster way?

Answer (score 1):

Selecting with Linq to SQL into Linq to XML

```
var document = new XDocument( 
   (
    from f in db.FirstTable
    select new XElement("Entity", 
                new XAttribute("title", f.TitleField),
                (            
                  from s in f.SecondTable
                  select new XElement("Entity",
                            new XAttribute("title", f.TitleField),
                            new XAttribute("Entity", f.SomeField)
                  )
                ).ToArray()
           )
   ).ToArray()
);
```

`XElement` constructor, as well as `XDocument`'s, accepts an array or content, that's why the `.ToArray()`.

Comment: that's may be a decision, but we have still 2.0 on production servers :). I will try with XMLDocument maybe.

Comment: You can compile it for .NET 2.0, no? (Correct me if it doesn't work with LINQ please)